# HTTP Request syntax in C

Tags: c, http, request

I am using the following code to copy a simple webpage into 'buffer'.

```
char sendBuffer[256];
ZeroMemory(sendBuffer, 256);
strcpy(sendBuffer, "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n\t<head>\r\n\t\t<title>403 - Forbidden</title>\r\n\t</head>\r\n\t<body>\r\n\t\t<h1>403 - Forbidden</h1>\r\n\t</body>\r\n</html>");
```

This works in Firefox, however Chrome just kind of crashes.

I am using \r\n as the 'CRLF' which I have been told to use, is this correct?

Comment: Is your buffer big enough to hold the string?

Comment: HTMl has no \t identifier

Comment: I edited my post to show more code (declaration and zero memory call). Yes my buffer is big enough. Magn3s1um, that could well be the cause. What should I replace \t with to make a tab? (put it as an answer so I can accept if it fixes the problem)

Comment: There should be no problem with `\t`, but perhaps Chrome requires a `Content-Length` header in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `Content-Length` header. This is not necessary if you include `Connection: close` as a header to indicate the close of the connection will signal the end of content.

```
const char msg[] =
"HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"
"Connection: close\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
"\r\n"
"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n"
"<html>\r\n"
"\t<head>\r\n"
"\t\t<title>403 - Forbidden</title>\r\n"
"\t</head>\r\n"
"\t<body>\r\n"
"\t\t<h1>403 - Forbidden</h1>\r\n"
"\t</body>\r\n</html>"
;

char sendBuffer[256];
snprintf(sendBuffer, sizeof(sendBuffer), "%s", msg);
```

You otherwise would have to dynamically or statically insert the message body length into a `Content-Length` header.

```
const char msg_header[] =
"HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"
"Content-Length: %d\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
"\r\n"
"%s"
;

const char msg_body[] =
"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n"
"<html>\r\n"
"\t<head>\r\n"
"\t\t<title>403 - Forbidden</title>\r\n"
"\t</head>\r\n"
"\t<body>\r\n"
"\t\t<h1>403 - Forbidden</h1>\r\n"
"\t</body>\r\n</html>"
;

char sendBuffer[256];
snprintf(sendBuffer, sizeof(sendBuffer), msg_header,
         sizeof(msg_body)-1, msg_body);
```

As Eddy_Em points out, there is no need to declare `Connection: close` if the server actually closes the connection. If your server is not closing the connection after issuing this message, the content length is required.

Comment: That's no need to write "connection: close" if you close it!

Comment: I tried both of these solutions, none of them work in Chrome at all, and the second one makes Firefox say "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." half of the time (sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't).

Comment: @Eddy_Em: You're right, I am not able to reproduce the reported behavior with Chrome.

Comment: That -1 fixed it. Working great now! Thanks.